# PDO global usage

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Lately, i was working on some WordPress sites and i was influenced by their DRY principle. So i started to work on it as well, using multiple functions. My problem that I have right now is that:

I have a PDO connection to MySql server and several functions that need this connection. I declared my $pdo as a global , so i can use it in my functions as well, but I can't understand why, when i use it in functions, it says that it is not recognised.. Here is an exemple :
db.php

```
global $pdo;
try  {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_mysql.';dbname='.$db_mysql.'',$user_mysql,$pass_mysql);
} catch(PDOExcetion $e) {
    $output='Error';
    echo $output;
    exit();
}
```

functions.php

```
require_once('db.php');
function test() {
    $sql ="/*Some mysql here*/";
    $pdo->exec($sql);                // and this is the line where i get the error
}
```

I solved this problem by putting the $pdo as arrgument for every single function, but as i have a quite big project, it slows me a lot. Is there any way I can declare my $pdo so it would be recognized in functions as well?

Comment: might it be cause there is a db.php already? and it's using the other

Comment: `$GLOBALS['pdo']` should do the trick or add `global $pdo` in every function where you need this global.

Comment: The `global` keyword must appear _inside_ the function `test()`. You can use `$GLOBALS['pdo']` there instead of `$pdo`, and it would work, but you must search/replace in all your code. See [this excellent post on variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: The best solution is to pass `$pdo` as an argument to all functions. That is really the way forward.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, why is this better than using a global in this case?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I used it as my single solution, but i prefer $GLOBALS as there are lots of functions using this connection and it would be even harder to add that extra argument for each one and each call. However, thanks for that post, it helps me in understanding the way variable works in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the global available.

```
require_once('db.php');
function test()
{
   global $pdo;
    $sql ="/*Some mysql here*/";
   $pdo->exec($sql);                
}
```

or

```
require_once('db.php');
function test()
{
   global $pdo;
    $sql ="/*Some mysql here*/";
   $GLOBALS['pdo']->exec($sql);           
}
```

Comment: i solved it with  $GLOBALS['pdo'], thanks a lot guys!